# Fast way to inverse B'CB+D

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, inverse

<strike>$\mathbf {A = B'CB}$, where $\mathbf A$ is of dimension $n \times n$, $\mathbf C$ is *m* by *m*, positive definite and symmetric, $\mathbf B$ is of dimension $m \times n$, and $n >> m$. Inversion of $A$ is computationally expensive. How can I take advantage of the fact that $\mathbf {A = B'CB}$ so that I can compute $\mathbf A^{-1} $ more quickly?</strike>

Furthermore, I want to know if there is a good way to inverse $\mathbf V$ where $\mathbf {V = B'CB + D}$ and $\mathbf D$ is a diagonal matrix. The economic interpretation of this formula is: $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf V$ are covariance-variance matrices, $\mathbf B$ is $\beta$ loading matrix, $\mathbf D$ is residual variances. Same as above, the size of $\mathbf V$ $>>$ the size of $\mathbf C$.

---

Updated on Jul-21-2014  :
Thanks to @copper.hat I realized that $\mathbf {A = B'CB}$ is not invertible if B is not full rank. I'll edit my question as below:

I want to know if there is a good way to inverse $\mathbf V$, where

- $\mathbf {V = B'CB + D}$,
- $\mathbf V$ is of dimension $n \times n$,
- $\mathbf C$ is of dimension $m \times m$, positive definite and symmetric,
- $\mathbf B$ is of dimension $m \times n$,
- $\mathbf D$ is a diagonal matrix, and the diagonal items are positive
- $n >> m$.

Inversion of $\mathbf V$ is computationally expensive. How can I take advantage of the fact that $\mathbf {V = B'CB + D}$ so that I can compute $\mathbf V^{-1} $ more quickly?

The economic interpretation of this formula is: $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf V$ are covariance-variance matrices. V is the cov-var matirx of all individual random variables. C is the cov-var matrix of some common factors.  $\mathbf B$ is $\beta$ loading matrix, $\mathbf D$ is residual variances.

---

More updates:

Notice that when $m = 1$, we have
$$
\mathbf {V^{-1} =  D^{-1} - \left(\frac{1}{1+\kappa }\right) \hat B' C \hat B}
$$
where 
$$
\kappa = \sum_{i=0}^N \left(\frac{\sigma^2 \beta_i^2}{\theta_i^2 }\right)  
$$
$$
\mathbf {B'} = \left(\beta_1, \beta_2, ... , \beta_N \right) 
$$
$$
\mathbf {\hat B'} = \left(\frac{\beta_1}{\theta_1^2 },\frac{\beta_2}{\theta_2^2 },...,\frac{\beta_N}{\theta_N^2 }\right) 
$$

$$
\mathbf C = \left(
        \begin{matrix}
        \sigma^2 
        \end{matrix}
\right)
$$
$$
\mathbf D = diag \left(\theta_1^2, \theta_2^2, ... , \theta_N^2 \right) 
$$

Is there a way to extend the formula above to cases where $m>1$ ?

Comment: How can $A$ be invertible if $n >m$?

Comment: A is n by n. In this question, assume that A, C and V are all invertible.

Comment: If $n>m$ then it is impossible for $A$ to be invertible.

Comment: Can you help me understand why A is not invertible when n>m? I'm not able to work out the proof of that. Also, if that's true, how about the second part of my question? Can I compute $V^{-1}$ easily by leveraging the fact that V=B'CB+D?

Comment: Any matrix $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, with $n>m$ must have a non-trivial kernel (that is, there is some $x\neq 0$ such that $Bx=0$. Hence $B^T CB x = 0$ also). This follows from the reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Thank you very much @copper.hat. You are absolutely right. I'll modify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar to the  original problem recently. Unfortunately I cannot give you a solution because I am working in a commercial company and don't have right to publish my results. However I can give you few hints.
1. Try to  build  recursion. $V_n^{-1}=f(V_{n-1}^{-1})$. Here $V_n$ is $nxn$ matrix built from $V_{n-1}$ by adding 1 row and 1 column. 
2. Use Woodberry identity for building recursion, namely

EDITED

$$
    \left(D+B^TCB\right)^{-1} = D^{-1} - D^{-1}B^T \left(C^{-1}+BA^{-1}B^T \right)^{-1}B D^{-1}, 
$$
Playing with  1 and 2 I build an efficient way for inversion. More presicely I can calculate $x^TV^{-1}x$ and $\det V$ which are necessary for mulitvariate likelihoods. Since your model resemebles  me a multi factor model of risk - may be you don't need $V^{-1}$ but these quantities.

Actually Woodberry identity even without any recursion indeed gives you a way to inverse your matrix much faster, since $D$ is diagonal and $C$ has much smaller dimension. You just have inverse in a similar form
$$
V^{-1}=D^{-1}-\tilde B^T \tilde C \tilde B
$$

Comment: Big thanks! Having this Woodbury matrix identity is already a big step forward for me.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to make your life a little easier :).